# Why does useState not work with Objects when using defaultValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, use-state

I have this Object:

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    test: "someRandomValue"
  });
```

And I want to use this in this input:

```
<input defaultValue={value.test} />
```

---

**Problem**

Normally when you just use useState this way (useState("someRandomValue")), the input updates its value when the state value is changed, but when you use a object,
it doesen´t update.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with the useState it also work with objects as well try setting

```
<input value={value.test} />
```

Comment: This is not a solution, because if you want do type into the input it is locked.

Comment: for that you can use 

<input value={value.test} onChange={(event)=> {setValue(event.target.value)}}/>

Comment: I have this on 40 values and if I do it like this, I have to much useless code.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) is correct.

The problem is with the input tag. You should give to the value attribute of the input tag the value of the state and add [onChange](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-onchange-events-with-examples) event to the input, which is going to update the state with the setValue function.

```
<input value={value.test} onChange={funcToUpdateState}/>
```